# using properties files in groovy

Tags: groovy, properties

I would like to externalize all my string constants in my groovy classes to a properies file, and then have them called from there. I have seen the example with the configslurper, want to know how can I make the design such that I just include/import/load the resource/property file in my class and call the property I want to on it..

something like this in my controller

```
include/load propertyfilename

if (propertyfilename.propertyname == mygroovyVar) {
....some code
}
```

i.e if possible I want to avoid using "(quotes) when retrieving properties anywhere

like the resource bundle setup for properties in spring mvc

Regards
Priyank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

something.groovy:

```
def loadConfig(environment,settingFileName) {
    levelConfig = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File(settingFileName).toURI().toURL())."$environment"
}
```

To access it :

```
def configFile  = loadConfig("alpha","c:\somewhere\something.properties" 
assert configFile.currlevel = "alpha"
```

something.properties:

```
alpha  {
currlevel = "alpha"
}
beta {
currlevel = "beta"
}
prod {
currlevel = "prod"
}
```

If you dont want the environment tweak it a bit. Hope this can help.